# How to resolder the wires to these two switches?

Tags: switches, soldering, wire

[image: Stuffed animal 1]

[image: Stuffed animal 2]

These two stuffed animals no longer light up. I opened them both up and found that one of the wires to each of their on/off button switches has broken off entirely. All other parts seem to be intact. My question is, can I just resolder the wires, or is there anything else I need to do to reinforce them? Like using heat shrink or hot glue, for instance.

Both wires are quite long, so stripping the wires isn't a problem. The components are partially sewn in, so removing them from the stuffed animal completely isn't practical.

Comment: Welcome! Just solder should last a while. Adding heat shrink or similar to provide strain relief would improve the situation.

Comment: Should go without saying, but if you're going to solder it while still attached to the fur / stuffing, be careful not to start a fire and have a plan ready for if you do!

Comment: I would liberally blob hot-glue all over that once re-soldered. It may not last forever, but it'll probably last 5x longer than before.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much already answered it yourself. If you are familiar with soldering then do like this:

- Very carefully cover the fur when working, so that you won't get solder splatter or flux splatter on it. It looks like the switch is removable, in that case just remove it from the animal before working.
- Desolder both wires and any remains of them from the switch.
- Clean the switch legs with a solder wick braid.
- Cut off the exposed part of the wires and peel them anew.
- Cut some heat shrink tubes appromixately 10mm and place the cut tube further up the wires, to be heated later.
- Pre-apply a bit of solder to the wires before soldering to the switch legs. Avoid a bend on where the wire meets the leg like on the yellow wire in the picture. The wire should be held straight against the leg.
- Pull down the heat shrink tube across the joint and heat with a heat gun.
- Optionally also cover it with hot glue at the end for mechanical strain relief.

Answer (score 0):

When you strip the wire, quickly, really within 3-5 seconds, cover it with solder or at least liquid flux. It looks like the ones that oxidize. After that simply clean the button leads and solder the wire.

I would say that you need to strip around 3mm of the wire.